# Group Results per Month using Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm still trying to figured out to achieve this using Mongo. Hope anyone here can teach me and help me with my problem.

Here's my schema

```
    const User = {
    table: 'User',
    schema: {
        _id: {
            name : 'Id',
            type: db.keyType(),
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            name: 'Email',
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
          }
}
```

desired results "19-12" is 19 = 2019 year and month 12 = December

```
    {
  "19-12": "5",
  "20-1": "22",
  "20-2": "20",
  "20-3": "4",
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. How did you arrive that pattern 19-12 from the data?

Comment: its from schema createdAt